# Smart Phone & Tablet - Plugged Into Computer

Tags: android, cocoa-touch, cocoa, connection, device

Is there a way to determine if a smart phone or tablet (iOS or Android), is plugged into a computer?

Either the phone/tablet perspective (i.e. `isConnectedToComputer`) or the computer perspective (i.e. `connectedDevices`) would be fine.

If it's from the computer perspective, it would specifically have to be via a Mac OS X app.
If it's from the phone/tablet perspective, it would need to be differentiated from simply `charging`.

The general idea is to determine when a user is at their computer.

*Note:* In order to make this determination, I need to identify the device. For iOS, the device UUID (similar to that used in APNS) is used. In Android, a combination hardware and software IDs are combined. So if the solution in from the computer perspective, I need to be able to obtain these strings. Otherwise, I need to be able to pass them to the computer.

**Bonus:** It would be fantastic if Wi-Fi syncing could also be taken into account as "connected".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple Solution**

Consider using `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` through `NSTask`.
When my iPhone is connected the following is included in the result:

```
iPhone:

 Product ID: 0x1292
 Vendor ID: 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.)
 Version: 0.01
 Serial Number: 
 Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
 Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
 Location ID: 0xfa140000 / 6
 Current Available (mA): 500
 Current Required (mA): 500
 Extra Operating Current (mA): 500
```

Use `system_profiler SPUSBDataType -xml` to output the result in `XML` format:

```
<dict>
    <key>_name</key>
    <string>iPhone</string>
    <key>a_product_id</key>
    <string>0x1292</string>
    <key>b_vendor_id</key>
    <string>apple_vendor_id</string>
    <key>c_bcd_device</key>
    <string> 0.01</string>
    <key>d_serial_num</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>e_device_speed</key>
    <string>high_speed</string>
    <key>f_manufacturer</key>
    <string>Apple Inc.</string>
    <key>g_location_id</key>
    <string>0xfa140000 / 6</string>
    <key>h_bus_power</key>
    <string>500</string>
    <key>j_bus_power_used</key>
    <string>500</string>
    <key>k_extra_current_used</key>
    <string>500</string>
</dict>
```

Simply parse the `XML` to determine wether the device of interest is connected or not.

Comment: Regarding iPhones/iPads: Is there a way to get the Hardware UUID from this application?

Comment: Running `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType -xml` shows the UUID for the Mac itself, look for the `<key>platform_UUID</key>` key. Unfortunately `system_profiler` cannot provide the UUID for connected iDevices.

Comment: As much as I love the simplicity of this answer, it doesn't quite give me 100% of the information I need from each device. I've added some more context into the question, and will be letting it go unanswered for the time being. Thanks again though!

Comment: I think that I was looking for the wrong solution to my actual problem, so this definitely is right for my question here.